# How to access value from json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get the value of phonenumber from below json

```
  array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ResponseStatus"]=>
    int(1)
    ["numbers"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PhoneNumber"]=>
      string(12) "6778"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried `$response['response']['numbers'][0]['PhoneNumber']` & `$response['response']['numbers']->PhoneNumber`

Comment: `$response['response']['numbers']['PhoneNumber']`

Comment: i have tried that also not working

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. If that is indeed the output PHP gives it simply has to work. Otherwise this question is missing crucial information.

Comment: Yes it should work, I ll try again with that

Comment: Can you please put `print_r($response);`, in the place you are trying to access the phone number from, then paste the output in your question.

Comment: @ccKep thanks bro its working

Answer (score 0):

I've tried looking at your code and replicated the Array myself, if you do:

```
echo $array["response"]["numbers"]["PhoneNumber"];
```

It should display the PhoneNumber value.